# How to calculate softmax for decreasing values?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, softmax

I am using a model for a multi-classification / ranking task, however for each choice problem it associates the different options with a number that is in a range with negative numbers with the caveat that the smallest number would actually correspond to the preferred choice. However, typically, softmax is applied to probabilities with the highest being the most likely to be the preferred choice. How could I adapt softmax to associate it with the highest probability? I have thought of using exp(-x) with x being the predicted number, but it does not work so well and there are no real mathematical justification in my view of doing so. In short, I would like to use a softmax like function that would associate to a set of n values amongst which some are negative a set of normalized probabilities (the sum of the n probabilities should be 1). The difference compared to the standard softmax function is that smallest value should be associated with the highest probability.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.